# About idempotent central elements in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Can any one help me in proving this:

> Let $e$ be an idempotent element in a ring $R$ which commutes with all idempotents, then $e$ is central.

I thought about this and get an answer if $R$ has a unit 1. But no such restriction is given. So how can it be?

Comment: A ring has a unit by definition.

Comment: @Glorfindel : in some conventions, rings need not have units

Comment: Not in all books.in some they don't demand the existence of a unit

Comment: I'm curious to know how having an identity helped you find a solution. @nour

Answer (score 6):

The thing is that for an arbitrary element $r$, $e+er-ere$ and $e+re-ere$ are also idempotents.

If $ e$ commutes with the first one, $e+er-ere=e(e+er-ere)=(e+er-ere)e=e$, and so $er=ere$.  By symmetry, $re=ere$ a too, so $er=re$.